# Vim Multi-line search pattern

Tags: vim, substitution

I have a substitute command that captures and displays submatch() values in the replacement string.  But I have another line of information that I want to parse below this line.  That line is always the first line after an empty line, though the number of lines TO that empty line varies.  For example:

```
The first important line I want to capture is here
Stuff I don't want.
A few more lines of stuff I don't want...

Second line I want to capture.
```

This pattern repeats a hundred or so times in a document.  I can substitute "The First Important Line" fine, but shouldn't that search pattern include a way to jump down to the first empty line and then pick up the next "Second line I want to capture."  ??  I could then place the contents of that second line into submatch parenthesis and substitute them where needed (right?).

If so, I cannot discover the way to extend the first search pattern to capture the "Second line"  Suggestions or correcting my approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone has already dealt with a similar problem. Below I provide their solution and the detailed description.

`/^\nF\d\_.\{-}\_^\n\zs.*/+`

> It means "Find a block of lines that start with F and a digit,
> then scan forward to the next blank line and select the line after that."

| Part of regex | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `^\n` | Matches the start of a line, followed by a newline - i.e a blank line |
| `F\d` | The next line starts with an F followed by a digit |
| `\_.\{-}` | `\_.` is like `.`, but also matches newline. `\{-}` matches the minimum number of the preceeding `\_.`. (If I were to use `*` instead of `\{-}`, it would match to near the end-of file.) |
| `\_^\n` | Matches a blank line. `\_^` is like `^`, but `^` only works at the start of a regular expression. |
| `\zs` | When the match is finished, set the start of match to this point. I use this because I don't want the preceding text to be highlighted. |
| `.*` | Matches the whole line. |

The `+` after the regular expression tells Vim to put the cursor on the line after the selection.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I think I read about offsets, but I can't find the bit in the help that is relevant right now. As such, my other solution would be to record a macro to do what you want:

```
qa/[Your pattern]<CR>jddq
```

You could then execute this macro with `@a` and repeat with `@@`; or run it a lot of times (e.g., `999@a`).